# URL Rewrite - Page Archive

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get a custom URL rewrite in place but having issues.

I have a page called 'Programme' which uses a custom query to list a post type called 'event'. I'd like to pass a month and day variable in the url, e.g. `/programme/09/31`

I'll then use the month / day variables to update the custom query. (As the events span multiple days the built in archive for 'events' won't work).

Currently trying to add the rewrite results in a 404. Can I use the built in 'm' and 'd' variables, or do I need to register new URL variables?

Thanks,

Ian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add following two functions in theme `functions.php` or in a plugin's php file

```
function func_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'programme/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=programme&pmonth=$matches[1]&pdate=$matches[2]',
        'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'func_rewrites_init');


function func_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'pmonth';
    $query_vars[] = 'pdate';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'func_query_vars' );
```

`pagename` value in the above code have to be according to template name. If you have a `Page` with slug `programme` template name will be `page-programme.php`. In that template file you can access month and date

```
$pmonth = get_query_var('pmonth');
$pdate = get_query_var('pdate');
```

One important thing from [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule):

> IMPORTANT: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules
>   database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens,
>   Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any
>   changes.

Comment: @chanchai118 that then redirects the 'programme' page to the homepage. Also oddly changes all the pages in wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page to (no title).

Comment: What is the name of your template file?

Comment: You also need to set `pagename=programme` In your rule.

Comment: Added pagename in rewrite rules.  So the template file should  be page-programme.tpl

Comment: @Milo Thanks, did the trick was trying p= and the ID before.

Comment: @chanchal118 - you also need to add 'add_action('init', 'func_rewrites_init');' to the example!

Comment: Also seems 'month' and 'day' don't work as the variable names (assuming it's confusing them with the builtin archives. For ease have renamed them 'pmonth' and 'pday'

Comment: yes, i will update answer accordingly